# What is the optimal way to check if document exists and insert based on outcome in CosmosDB?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We use a tracking table in CosmosDB to identify the status of the orders in CosmosDB.
{TrackingID, OrderID, Status}

We need to create a new document in the tracking table when there is no record for the Order with Status as Completed/InProgress.

Currently, we hit the Cosmos DB twice in the below code. Is it possible to create a stored procedure in CosmosDB and return the tracking id when the new record is inserted or return null when the Order is with Completed/InProgress status?

```
public static void InsertTracking(string OrderID)
{
    if(! IsOrderProcessedOrInProgress(OrderID))
    {
        var trackingID = CreateTracking(OrderID);
        NotifyNewTracking(trackingID);
    }
}
```

Comment: The short answer is yes; just read up on Cosmos stored procedures. Your requirement sounds simple enough for what you can do with them.

Comment: I should add a caveat is that you need to remain within the same partition key within each execution of the SP; whether you can do this in your scenario depends on how your container is configured.

Comment: Thanks, @sellotape for your suggestion. I will understand the stored procedure concept in Cosmos DB and implement it.

Comment: Please refer [stored procedures and triggers in Azure Cosmos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-write-javascript-query-api) and [Transactions within stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=javascript#transactions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can create a stored procedure in CosmosDB and return the tracking id or NULL by applying check using conditional statements.

Stored Procedures are written in **JavaScript** when it comes to the Cosmos DB context. They are written and stored at Collection Level and they provide a secure and transactional environment to perform complex sequences of operations.

You can write you stored procedure as shown in the below example snippet.

```js
function checkIfNotExists(orderID) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var response = getcontext().getResponse();
    
    // Query documents
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM o WHERE o.orderID="' + orderID + '"';
    var isStatus = collection.queryDocuments(...) {
            ...
            //run you condition to check and
            // update the response respectively.
    }
}
```

After that you must initialize the document client instance by adding a reference to to **Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client** and **Microsoft.Azure.Documents** in your **Program.cs**. Then you can executed the stored procedure by following the approach as shown below.

```cs
//Read Stored Procedure
var sprocBody = File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\StoredProcedures\checkIfNotExists.js");
//Create SP definition
var spDefinition = new StoredProcedure
{
    Id = "checkIfNotExists",
    Body = sprocBody
};

//Create a Store Procedure
StoredProcedure sproc = await client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumenCollectionUri("dbFamily", "Families"), spDefinition);
Console.WriteLine($"\r\nCreated Store procedure Id:{sproc.Id} ");

//Execute Store Procedure
 var result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>  (UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("dbFamily", "Families", "spHelloWorld"));
 Console.WriteLine($"Executed Store Procedure: response:{result.Response}");
```

Also note that as @sellotape said you need to remain within the same partition key within each execution of the SP. And after following all the above mentioned steps you should be able to achieve your desired result. I would suggest to read [Stored Procedures In Azure Cosmos DB](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/stored-procedures-in-azure-cosmos-db/) and [Stored Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/stored-procedures) for more information.